# Does index on IMap work with Kryo serialization?

Tags: hazelcast, kryo

I've created a Hazelcast IMap and defined some Index on value field. Does Index work with Kryo serialization ? I remember that in earlier version of Hazelcast index used to work only when in-memory-format was OBJECT.

Comment: No matter which in-memory-format you use, indexing works with Kryo serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes indeed works with Kryo serialization. When an entry is being Hazelcast deserializes it to extract indexed fields.